# Unable to access 'window' object in an angular expression without a controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to show a `<p>` only in the `HTTP` protocol.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
angular
.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window){

  $scope.name = 'Superhero';

  console.log('$window.location.protocol = ' + $window.location.protocol); // just checking

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

  <p ng-if="window.location.protocol === 'http:'">This needs to be shown in HTTP only.</p> <!-- doesnt work with $window either -->

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Hello, {{name}}!
  </div>

</div>
```

This snippet doesnt work in both `HTTP` and `HTTPS`.

I am pretty sure the problem is about accessing the `window` object.

How do I fix this?

---

**Edit:** Note that the `<p>` does not have any controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can use nothing but scope properties in expressions. That's [how they work](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angular-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions). It is

```
$scope.$root.protocol = $window.location.protocol;
```

and

```
<p ng-if="protocol  === 'http:'">This needs to be shown in HTTP only.</p>
```

Comment: @rahul-desai - even in this case <p> should be inside controller, right? how does this solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, @ManojShevate has the point. The code will be workable outside the controller (which is bad thing because the entire app should be controlled by 'ng-controller's or other directives) by assigning the variable to root scope, it will also be inherited by nested scopes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why $window is not working, but here is the solution you can try -

use comparison operator inside controller and then add model in rootscope which is accessible out side the controller scope -

refer below code snippet, Hope this will solve your problem -

```js
   angular
.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$window','$rootScope', function($scope, $window,$rootScope){

  $scope.name = 'Superhero';
  $rootScope.httpOnly = $window.location.protocol === 'http:'; 

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">

  <p ng-if="$root.httpOnly">Outside Controller</p>

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Hello, {{name}}!
  </div>

</div>
```